# How to set Drupal block position that will depend on current theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I have a website where I should support 2 different themes at the same time.
Themes are completely different, and I have a task to show some blocks in different regions for each theme.

For example:

In "Theme X" the "Search block" is located in left sidebar alongside with navigation and some other blocks.
For "Theme Y" the same "Search block" should be placed in the header of the page and look completely differently.

I've copied the file "search-theme-form.tpl.php" from "modules/search" directory and placed it inside each theme directory. There is no any problems with design but I can't find the way to set theme specific positions of blocks.

So lets say to have "Search" in "right-sidebar" region for "Theme X" 
and have same block in "header" region for "Theme Y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal's administration area will already let you do this. If you go to `/admin/build/block` you'll see a set of tabs for all the themes you have installed/active. You can go into each of these tabs to change the regions for blocks on a theme specific basis.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Wasn't able to notice those tabs, and all my requests like "drupal theme specific block positions", etc... were not successful in Google.

Possibly this topic will be useful for others who have the same issue.